# Colorize plantuml activity diagram

Tags: colors, activity-diagram, plantuml

I want to set a custom skin for my activity diagrams. I only managed to set the skin for activities:

```
skinparam activity {
    BackgroundColor #AAAAAA
    BorderColor #BBBBBB
}
```

Is it possible to set custom colors for conditions and loops, too?

Thanks in advance!
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
skinparam activityDiamondBackgroundColor #AAAAAA
skinparam activityDiamondBorderColor #BBBBBB
```

or:

```
skinparam activity {
    DiamondBackgroundColor #AAAAAA
    DiamondBorderColor #BBBBBB
}
```

found in [ColorParam.java](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/blob/master/src/net/sourceforge/plantuml/ColorParam.java)

The default color for background is `#FEFECE`, search the source file, got `MY_YELLOW`, then search `MY_YELLOW`, got `activityDiamondBackground`, then I tried `activityDiamondBackgroundColor`, and it works.